# Understand Scipy's Savitzky- Golay filter implementation

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

Scipy's cookbook documentation gives the following code

```
def savitzky_golay(y, window_size, order, deriv=0, rate=1):
    r"""Smooth (and optionally differentiate) data with a Savitzky-Golay filter.
    The Savitzky-Golay filter removes high frequency noise from data.
    It has the advantage of preserving the original shape and
    features of the signal better than other types of filtering
    approaches, such as moving averages techniques.
    Parameters
    ----------
    y : array_like, shape (N,)
        the values of the time history of the signal.
    window_size : int
        the length of the window. Must be an odd integer number.
    order : int
        the order of the polynomial used in the filtering.
        Must be less then `window_size` - 1.
    deriv: int
        the order of the derivative to compute (default = 0 means only smoothing)
    Returns
    -------
    ys : ndarray, shape (N)
        the smoothed signal (or it's n-th derivative).
    Notes
    -----
    The Savitzky-Golay is a type of low-pass filter, particularly
    suited for smoothing noisy data. The main idea behind this
    approach is to make for each point a least-square fit with a
    polynomial of high order over a odd-sized window centered at
    the point.
    Examples
    --------
    t = np.linspace(-4, 4, 500)
    y = np.exp( -t**2 ) + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, t.shape)
    ysg = savitzky_golay(y, window_size=31, order=4)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(t, y, label='Noisy signal')
    plt.plot(t, np.exp(-t**2), 'k', lw=1.5, label='Original signal')
    plt.plot(t, ysg, 'r', label='Filtered signal')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    References
    ----------
    .. [1] A. Savitzky, M. J. E. Golay, Smoothing and Differentiation of
       Data by Simplified Least Squares Procedures. Analytical
       Chemistry, 1964, 36 (8), pp 1627-1639.
    .. [2] Numerical Recipes 3rd Edition: The Art of Scientific Computing
       W.H. Press, S.A. Teukolsky, W.T. Vetterling, B.P. Flannery
       Cambridge University Press ISBN-13: 9780521880688
    """
    import numpy as np
    from math import factorial

    try:
        window_size = np.abs(np.int(window_size))
        order = np.abs(np.int(order))
    except ValueError, msg:
        raise ValueError("window_size and order have to be of type int")
    if window_size % 2 != 1 or window_size < 1:
        raise TypeError("window_size size must be a positive odd number")
    if window_size < order + 2:
        raise TypeError("window_size is too small for the polynomials order")
    order_range = range(order+1)
    half_window = (window_size -1) // 2
    # precompute coefficients
    b = np.mat([[k**i for i in order_range] for k in range(-half_window, half_window+1)])
    m = np.linalg.pinv(b).A[deriv] * rate**deriv * factorial(deriv)
    # pad the signal at the extremes with
    # values taken from the signal itself
    firstvals = y[0] - np.abs( y[1:half_window+1][::-1] - y[0] )
    lastvals = y[-1] + np.abs(y[-half_window-1:-1][::-1] - y[-1])
    y = np.concatenate((firstvals, y, lastvals))
    return np.convolve( m[::-1], y, mode='valid')
```

On their website, they refer to an article, but I can't really see how the algorithm in that paper match with the code. My main problem is understanding the coefficient m, matrix b and y = np.concatenate((firstvals, y, lastvals)). I understand that SG is based on least squares polynomial smoothing.

The link to the article on SG is [HERE](https://www.wire.tu-bs.de/OLDWEB/mameyer/cmr/savgol.pdf)

Comment: FYI: That cookbook code is old.  The actual scipy functions are [`scipy.signal.savgol_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) and, if you want the filter coefficients without applying the filter,  [`scipy.signal.savgol_coeffs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_coeffs.html).  The implementation is in the file [scipy/signal/_savitzky_golay.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/_savitzky_golay.py).

Comment: At issue with this code is considered in [Scipy implementation of Savitzky-Golay filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49322932#49330505)

Comment: Thank you, sir. The new implementation was more like the one in the article and easier to understand. 1 upvote for you, sir

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser BTW one thing, do you know what the ys are in savgol_coeffs? From the article, it would be logical if y was the sample points. It's just weird that we can calculate the coefficients without knowing anything about the signal we want to smooth.

Comment: That's a fundamental property of the [Savitzky-Golay filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter).  The coefficients don't depend on the data values, so you can use the same coefficients at each sample in the time series.  That means applying the filter is simply a convolution of the time series data with the coefficients.  (In other words, it is a [finite impulse response filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response).)