# What is the Python equivalent for MATLAB's sgolay(k, f)?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I have a function in MATLAB

```
[b,g] = sgolay(k, f);
```

It outputs a f x f matrix.

When I run the same for the same values of k and f in Python, using:

```
scipy.signal.savgol_coeffs(f, k)
```

It outputs an entirely different array of only f elements.

The values in consideration are:

> k = 4, f = 21

`savol_filter()` takes three arguments, including the array, whereas `sgolay()` takes only two. Also, the `savo_coeffs` is not generating the required matrix.

What is the Python equivalent for obtaining the matrix generated by sgolay(k, f) in matlab?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322932/scipy-implementation-of-savitzky-golay-filter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scipy implementation of Savitzky-Golay filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322932/scipy-implementation-of-savitzky-golay-filter)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322932/scipy-implementation-of-savitzky-golay-filter.  It is specifically asking for how to generate the square matrix returned by Matlab's `sgolay` function, which is not mentioned in the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the matrix `b` returned by Matlab's [`sgolay`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sgolay.html) function, you'll see that the *center row* is the same as the 1-d array returned by SciPy's `savgol_coeffs`.  The upper and lower halves of `b`, with `(framelen - 1)/2` rows in each part, are the coefficients of the Savitzky-Golay filters to be applied to the ends of the signal, where the filter is not symmetric. That is, for the `(framelen - 1)/2` values at each end of the signal, each filtered value is computed using a different set of coefficients.

You can use `savgol_coeffs` to generate `b` by iterating over the `pos` argument.  The following ipython session shows an example.

```
In [74]: import numpy as np

In [75]: from scipy.signal import savgol_coeffs

In [76]: np.set_printoptions(precision=11, linewidth=90)

In [77]: order = 3

In [78]: windowlen = 5
```

These are the coefficients of the symmetric (i.e. centered) Savitzky-Golay filter.  The 1-d array should match the center row of the matrix returned by `sgolay`:

```
In [79]: savgol_coeffs(windowlen, order)
Out[79]: array([-0.08571428571,  0.34285714286,  0.48571428571,  0.34285714286, -0.08571428571])
```

If we set `pos=windowlen-1`, we get coefficients designed for evaluating the filter at one end of the window.  These should match the first row of the array returned by `sgolay`:

```
In [80]: savgol_coeffs(windowlen, order, pos=windowlen-1)
Out[80]: array([ 0.98571428571,  0.05714285714, -0.08571428571,  0.05714285714, -0.01428571429])
```

Similarly, `pos=0` gives the coefficients for the other end of the window.  These should match the last row of the matrix returned by `sgolay`:

```
In [81]: savgol_coeffs(windowlen, order, pos=0)
Out[81]: array([-0.01428571429,  0.05714285714, -0.08571428571,  0.05714285714,  0.98571428571])
```

Here's the full array to match the return value of Matlab's `sgolay`:

```
In [82]: b = np.array([savgol_coeffs(windowlen, order, pos=p) for p in range(windowlen-1, -1, -1)])

In [83]: b
Out[83]: 
array([[ 0.98571428571,  0.05714285714, -0.08571428571,  0.05714285714, -0.01428571429],
       [ 0.05714285714,  0.77142857143,  0.34285714286, -0.22857142857,  0.05714285714],
       [-0.08571428571,  0.34285714286,  0.48571428571,  0.34285714286, -0.08571428571],
       [ 0.05714285714, -0.22857142857,  0.34285714286,  0.77142857143,  0.05714285714],
       [-0.01428571429,  0.05714285714, -0.08571428571,  0.05714285714,  0.98571428571]])
```

If you compare this to the result of `b = sgolay(3, 5)` in Matlab, you'll see that they are the same.

To get the `g` matrix returned by `sgolay`, you'll have to call `savgol_coeffs` with `deriv` set to the values in `range(order+1)`, reverse and transpose the array, and scale by the factorial of the derivative order.  To reverse the coefficients, you could use a slice of the form `::-1`, or you can use the `use` option of `savgol_coeffs`.

Here's one way to use `savgol_coeffs` to generate the `g` matrix with `order=3` and `windowlen=5`:

```
In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: from scipy.signal import savgol_coeffs

In [14]: from scipy.special import factorial

In [15]: np.set_printoptions(precision=11, linewidth=90, suppress=True)

In [16]: order = 3

In [17]: windowlen = 5

In [18]: g = np.array([savgol_coeffs(windowlen, order, deriv=d, use='dot') for d in range(order+1)]).T / factorial(np.arange(order+1))

In [19]: g
Out[19]: 
array([[-0.08571428571,  0.08333333333,  0.14285714286, -0.08333333333],
       [ 0.34285714286, -0.66666666667, -0.07142857143,  0.16666666667],
       [ 0.48571428571,  0.           , -0.14285714286,  0.           ],
       [ 0.34285714286,  0.66666666667, -0.07142857143, -0.16666666667],
       [-0.08571428571, -0.08333333333,  0.14285714286,  0.08333333333]])
```

You don't say why you want the full `windowlen` x `windowlen` array in Python.  You don't need it to use `savgol_filter`.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. Another question. How about the g matrix generated by the MATLAB function? Is `a = savgol_coeffs(window_length, polyorder, deriv=1)`  equal to `g(:,1)` for the g in MATLAB.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example that shows how to compute `g`.