# MATLAB to Python [sgolay()]

Tags: python, matlab

A MATLAB code contains the use of the function sgolay as:

```
[b,g] = sgolay(k, f)
```

Using this, I need to find the smoothness, first derivative, and second derivative. for finding the above, I need the value of `g`.

These have to be performed in Python instead of MATLAB.

Python's `savgol_filter(arr, k, f)` works the same as MATLAB's `sgolay(arr, k, f)`, however, there is no alternative to `sgolay(k, f)` which designs the filter and returns `g`.

What would be a Python equivalent to the sgolay() function?

Comment: So, what's the question? This seems to be missing here. Questions in English are denoted by a question mark, ?, and can receive an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Python equivalent for MATLAB's sgolay(k, f)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850399/what-is-the-python-equivalent-for-matlabs-sgolayk-f)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem now. (You had a typo, you meant sgolayfilt(arr, k, f) instead of sgolay(arr, k, f).)

So,

MATLAB's `sgolayfilt` is related to python's `savgol_filter`

MATLAB's `sgolay` is related to python's `savgol_coeffs`

Note that, in python's function, the order of the parameters is:

```
smoothingfilter = savgol_coeffs(window_length, polyorder)
```

while in MATLAB is the other way around:

```
[smoothingfilter,g] = sgolay(ORDER,FRAMELEN)
```

If you now want the differentiation filters, which in matlab are in `g` you will need to pass that optional parameter to the python function:

```
smoothingfilter_deriv = savgol_coeffs(window_length, polyorder, deriv)
```

which will be derived deriv times. In your particular case, you want:

```
smoothingfilter1 = savgol_coeffs(window_length, polyorder, 1)

smoothingfilter2 = savgol_coeffs(window_length, polyorder, 2)
```

that are the python's equivalent to:

```
g(:,1) (for smoothingfilter1)
```

and

```
g(:,2) (for smoothingfilter2)
```

where g was obtained doing:

```
[b,g] = sgolay(polyorder,window_length)
```